# Use of directorial numbers to determine the equation of a sphere

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

**Problem**: Given the line $$ passing through the two points $(1; -2; 0)$ and $(2; 3; -1)$, determine the equation
Cartesian of the spherical surface of center $(1; -6; 7)$ and tangent to $$.

**Partial solution**: the line $r$ in parametric form is:
$$\mathbf{v}=(l,m,n)=(x_B-x_A,y_B-y_A,z_B-z_A)$$

$$\begin{cases}x=x_A+lt=1+t \\ y=y_A+mt=-2+5t \\ z=z_A+nt=-t \end{cases}$$ with $t\in \Bbb R$.

Since the spherical surface is tangent to the line $$, its radius $$ will be equal to the distance between its
center $(1; -6; 7)$ and the line $$. To calculate the distance between $$ and $$, we need to determine the equation
of the plane $$ passing through $$ and perpendicular to the line $$.

> Why the plane $$ use the directorial numbers $l,m,n$? I.e.

$$l(x-1)+m(y+6)+n(z-7)=0, \quad ?$$

Comment: $(l,m,n)$ is the direction vector of the line. Equating the dot product with this direction vector to zero gives the set of all vectors perpendicular to the line direction, i.e. the plane perpendicular to that direction.

Comment: @AndreasLenz Is there a proof? Could you kindly add an answer? I don't remember doing something similar in college 24 years ago. I am a high school teacher and much of my cultural background has been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Claim 1.*
Suppose you are given a vector $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then, the plane of vectors perpendicular to $a$ is the set of vectors defined by
$$ \{ b=(b_1,b_2,b_3) : a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3=0 \}. $$
*Proof.*
Let $|a|$ and $|b|$ be the lengths of the vector $a$ and $b$, respectively. Then, by the Pythagorean theorem, $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular if and only if
\begin{align*}
|a|^2+|b|^2 &= |a-b|^2 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \\
a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2 + b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2 &= (a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2+(a_3-b_3)^2 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \\
a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2 + b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2 &= a_1^2+b_1^2-2a_1b_1+a_2^2+b_2^2-2a_2b_2+a_3^2+b_3^2-2a_3b_3 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \\
0&=-2a_1b_1-2a_2b_2-2a_3b_3.
\end{align*}
Dividing by $-2$ gives the desired result.

**Back to your question.**

Using Claim 1, the plane of vectors $(x',y',z')$ perpendicular to $(l,m,n)$ is given by
$$lx'+my'+nz'=0.$$
It is quickly verified that this plane passes through $(x',y',z')=(0,0,0)$. So, in a second step, we translate the plane to pass through $C$ by setting $(x,y,z) = (x',y',z')+(1,-6,7)$, which gives the result
$$l(x-1)+m(y+6)+n(z-7)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Never done in my University.

Comment: Glad it helped :)